# How can I plot $X, Y, Z$ in 3D chart in Graphing Calculator 3D

Tags: graphing-functions, 3d, math-software

I couldn't do it in Excel. Can I draw a $X, Y, Z$ plot using Graphing Calculator 3D?

Comment: depends which calculator. you can definitely do it in Excel. which chart exactly do you want to see?

Comment: @gt6989b Graphing calculator 3D is a product from a company called [runiter](https://www.runiter.com/). Look at G. C. 3D's  [help page](https://www.runiter.com/graphing-calculator/help.htm), it seems it doesn't support it directly in current version. I believe the author of the software is a member of math.SE and he has answered a lot of G.C. 3D's related question. Just wait and see.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest way to do that is to create a new project in Graphing Calculator 3D, then simply start typing your x,y,z coordinates in the table of values located in the middle of the window. As soon as you do so the graph type will be converted from equation to table.

If you already have your data in an excel spreadsheet, you can export it to a csv file, then import it in Graphing Calculator 3D.

Or, you can simply copy the 3 columns of numbers and paste them in the table of values in Graphing Calculator 3D.

If you import lots of coordinates, you may want to push the zoomAll button to automatically adjust your axis settings to include all your points.